# How does the knot contact homology augmentation polynomial change under a surgery on the base manifold?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, contact-geometry

So for every knot $K \in S^3$, there is a knot contact homology of $K$, and we can find the augmentation variety for this homology. The defining polynomial is known as the augmentation polynomial $A(K)$, which, as Aganagic *et al.* conjectured, corresponds to the classical A-polynomial when setting $Q=1$.

Now my question is that, how does this $A(K)$ change when I do surgery on $S^3$. As a concrete example, I want to find $K=\text{unknot}$ and the surgery is the contact surgery manifold obtained on a Legendrian unknots. It has Thurston-Bennequin number $\mathtt{tb} = -2$ and surgery coefficient $-1$.

What I knew was that "contact" surgery with coefficient $-1$ is equivalent to attaching a Legendrian handle on the manifold, so in that case is simply a good old Legendrian surgery.

My thought was that this surgery changes the symplectization from simply $\mathbb R\times S^3$ to $\mathbb R\times M^3$, but now the picture looks like this:

[image: surgery effect]

So I think from Ekholm's talk I learned that I need to consider the closed Reeb orbits, but I am stuck. Ekholm in one of his lectures calculated the value of unknot in $\mathbb RP^3$, but I do not understand how he arrived at his answer.

Is my above thinking correct? Or am I completely wrong? Thank you everyone!